# Decrypting kubernetes master api calls

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-security

Team,
I am running kubectl from my laptop and captured Wireshark trace of the same. how could I decrypt the traffic hitting the api server?

ex: we decrypt the http calls using private key of the web server. in k8s world, how would I decrypt the calls to cluster? new to this so need to understand.

Comment: Did you create the cluster or rather have a hold of the keys to create the cluster?

Answer (score 2):

The traffic itself and the (api)server keys will not be enough for that. Current TLS implementation is using [forward secrecy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) so you would need the session keys as well. Browsers can be configured to log session keys (which you can feed into wireshark) but I don't know if kubectl can be configured with some debugging options to do that. Probably not.

An alternative is a [man in the middle "attack"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) which will defeat TLS with forward secrecy. I capture kubectl traffic with [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy). You will need to set it up with kubernetes CA, so the generated certificates are valid as far as kubectl is concerned.

*Of course, all for educational purposes at trainings ;-)*

Comment: so, i can see live traffic on mitmproxy provided i use the k8s CA? but how do i redirect the kubectl calls to mitmproxy so that i can see the trafic?